# Converting from Activity to Fragment? Getting Null Pointer Exceptions

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, android-fragments

I'm working on a Madlib app. The code you see below is the class that handles gathering input from edittext boxes found in madlibinput1.xml, storing that info as strings, and then sending that text to the madliboutput.xml where it replaces all "wx" with input gathered in the input xml. This class used to be an activity, but I found making it a fragment helps implement my navigation drawer better. However, I am an almost complete beginner with fragments (and programming in general) and feel like I didn't convert my code to work with fragments very well.

Can someone help me figure out why I have a null pointer exception in the gather() method (and perhaps null pointers elsewhere) when I hit the convert button. Perhaps I am doing something wrong getting information about my xml or something to do with my views. It would be very appreciated thank you.

```
package com.shamu11.madlibsportable;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;

public class Madlibs extends Fragment {
int inLayout; // will hold the id number for layout file
                // main_class_activity_in.xml.
int outLayout; // will hold the id number for layout file
                // main_class_activity_out.xml.
int outviewid; // will hold the id number for the textview found in
                // main_class_activity_out.xml
//Activity activity = this;
String test;
AutoCompleteTextView autoview;
StringBuffer stringbuffer = new StringBuffer();
String[] stringviews = new String[16];

Button convert;

View view;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.madlibinput1, container, false);

    //setContentView(R.layout.madlibinput1);
    outLayout = (R.layout.madliboutput1);
    inLayout = (R.layout.madlibinput1);
    outviewid = (R.id.outview14);

    convert = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.convert);
    convert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            gather();
            postIt();
        }
    });

    return view;

}

public void gather() {

    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.anskey_clover);
    View[] views = new View[layout.getChildCount()];
    int[] ids = new int[layout.getChildCount()];

    for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        ids[i] = layout.getChildAt(i).getId();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        AutoCompleteTextView au = (AutoCompleteTextView) getActivity().findViewById(ids[i]);
        stringbuffer.append(au.getText().toString() + "\n");

    }

    //setContentView(outLayout);
    TextView outview = (TextView) getView().findViewById(outviewid);
    outview.setText(stringbuffer.toString());

}

public void postIt() {
    String str = "let's go to the park";
    String str2;
    String newstr = null;

    //setContentView(outLayout);
    TextView outview = (TextView) view.findViewById(outviewid);
    str = (String) outview.getText();
    stringviews = stringbuffer.toString().split("\n"); // turns the
                                                        // stringbuffer from
                                                        // getAllXml() into
                                                        // an array and
                                                        // assigns to
                                                        // stringviews.

    for (int i = 0; i < stringviews.length; i++) {
        str2 = stringviews[i];
        newstr = str.replaceFirst("wx", str2); // replaces all the "wx"s in
                                                // the
                                                // main_class_activity_out
                                                // textview with values from
                                                // strinvgviews.
        str = newstr;
    }
    outview.setText(newstr);
    stringbuffer.delete(0, stringbuffer.length());

    Fragment newFragment = new MadlibsOutput();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment1, newFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    transaction.commit();

}

}
```

madlibinput1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ffffff" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.39"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="184dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#ffffff" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/outview1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="1.) Adjective to Describe:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lvheader_song"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="2.) ing-verb (i.e. running):" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="3.) Negative Adjective:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="4.) Negative Verb:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="5.) Adjective" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="6.) Plural Noun:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="7.) Verb (ending in &apos;-ed&apos;):" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/anskey_clover"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="234dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/auview1"
            android:layout_width="141dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.40"
            android:ems="10"
            android:text="la dee dah" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/auview2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/auview3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/auview4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/auview5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/auview6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/auview7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/convert"
    android:layout_width="222dp"
    android:layout_height="93dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:text="Get My Mad Lib" />

</LinearLayout>
```

madliboutput1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/outview14"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="madlib text.........etc" />

</LinearLayout>
```

LOG CAT:

```
06-30 23:00:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5567): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-30 23:00:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5567): Process: com.shamu11.madlibsportable, PID: 5567
06-30 23:00:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5567): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-30 23:00:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5567):     at com.shamu11.madlibsportable.Madlibs.gather(Madlibs.java:78)
06-30 23:00:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5567):     at com.shamu11.madlibsportable.Madlibs$1.onClick(Madlibs.java:51)
06-30 23:00:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5567):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
06-30 23:00:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5567):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
06-30 23:00:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5567):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-30 23:00:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5567):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-30 23:00:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5567):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-30 23:00:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5567):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
06-30 23:00:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5567):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-30 23:00:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5567):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-30 23:00:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5567):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
06-30 23:00:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5567):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
06-30 23:00:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5567):     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
06-30 23:00:11.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5567):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: you get NPE on `outview.setText(stringbuffer.toString());` I think `outView` is null

Comment: I think proble is `getView().findViewById(outviewid);`

Comment: Post R.layout.madlibinput1 layout. Also it's not traditional to store the int ID of a view but usually a ref to the view itself.

Comment: Elaborating... the reason is because there is a semi expensive lookup every time you call findViewById(), so if you just cache the ref the first time you save some performance.

Comment: @sgarman Thank you for that tip! I have posted the input and output xml files. Thank you for your help! FYI: Instead of getView(), I am now using my inflated "view" variable. Example: "ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.anskey_clover);" is now ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.anskey_clover);

Comment: I TOTALLY FIXED IT! I needed to create a 2nd view to hold the output xml file. However my modified textview with the replaced text in the output xml file is not working, it still shows the original. Have to figure that out now.

Answer (score 0):

You try to find view in activity not in fragment, by this line:

```
AutoCompleteTextView au = (AutoCompleteTextView) getActivity().findViewById(ids[i]);
```